# Ubuntu Apt: not installing whole package

Tags: apt

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04LTS.
Using Apt, I have experimented with various programs, one of which I have repeatedly `apt-get install`-ed and `apt-get remove`-ed.

These days however, when I attempt to `sudo apt-get install` this program (suricata IDS), apt claims that the program is already installed, and has however been updated, and whilst directory systems in `/etc/` and `/var/` etc. exist; configuration files and rule-sets are not installed.

I suspect that apt isn't recognizing a manual uninstall I attempted some time ago, and so my idea is to reset Apt and hope that solves the issue.

In short: **Why isn't Apt installing the entirety of packages?**

Does anyone have any better ideas or solutions?

Comment: What exactly was the "manual uninstall" that you attempted? Have you tried adding  the `--reinstall` flag to your `apt-get install` command?

Comment: By manual uninstall I just ran "du -a /" and deleted all references to suricata that it returned, which I know is messy and won't delete it's references in init.d for example. Just tried with "--reinstall", no improvement :/